# Can I access google Calendar appointment slots using API or some Java client?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I cannot find any documentation for how to create/book/read Appointment Slots via the Google Calendar API.
Does Google provide any API support for the Appointment Slots feature?

Answer (score 1):

[Google Calendar appointment slots](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/190998?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Chow-appointment-slots-relate-to-regular-events) are something that was created with in the Google calendar web application.  Its the web app that controls support for appointment slots.  It is actually only available to google workspace domain accounts.

It would be interesting to see what the underlying event looks like when created as an appointment slot i cant say i have checked.  It may be something that could be completely recreated via the api if it is in fact just an event by another name. (I will try to find some time tomorrow to dig into it a little more.)

You may want to try and submit a feature request [issue forum](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191627%2B)

I think the closest you can get would be to create new events Using the [events.insert method](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert)

You can also make requests to see if the user is busy or free at that time [freebusy.query](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/freebusy/query)

Comment: I can confirm that there doesn't seem to be anything different in the API between events created manually and ones created by appointment slots, other than that the ones created with slots automatically add the participant and confirm their attendance. The appointment slots appear to be just a convenient UI way to allow other users to create events while preventing conflicts.

Comment: @Daniel cant you prevent conflicts by just checking free busy first?   That must be what they are doing with the ui

Comment: I agree. Since the events are no different and the functionality can be replicated with current API methods that's probably what they are already doing. Incidentally, I found the current issue tracker feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36757162). It's been there for a *long* time so who knows if it will be added. I think it's probably best to leverage the current methods to replicate the tool rather than wait.